# WordPress screen of death

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, web

My WordPress site suddenly shows a blank screen with no reason what so over. It's probably the theme, so I've replaced it, tried all the plugins, etc. My error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Less_Exception_Compiler' with message 'error evaluating function `fade` The first argument to fade must be a color index: 584 in header.less' in /home/greensq1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plethora-featureslib/features/module/wpless/wp-less/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Mixin/Call.php:130

Has anyone had that problem before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you disabled and/or deleted the plugin `plethora-featureslib`? Because the LESS in that plugin is not compiling and returning an error.

Comment: Hi there! So for what it's worth, the culprit is the "plethora-featureslib" plugin. If you disable that plugin, your site should at least load. As for fixing the actual issue, I would contact the plugin author with the PHP error you gave us - that should put them on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the theme.
Problem is in file header.less on line 584 with function fade.
I don't know if you made the theme yourself and if the function definition will tell you something
http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade

You can start by disabling plethora-featureslib plugin by renaming its directory. You should have access to wordpress then, but theme shouldn't be displayed properly.

Did the theme allow you to change its colors by admin panel? Did you maybe just did that? Function fade work with colors. However if it encounters color it cannot understand a problem like that can occur.
If you indeed changed the color, then change the color back to what it was, and try to turn the plethora-featureslib plugin on again (by renaming directory back to what it was).
Be careful when changing colors again, as it seems that theme doesn't have any check against non valid colors.

Comment: Man thank you so much. This solved my problem. You saved me so much time. I just had to change the color back and its working again.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your plethora-featureslib plugin to plethora-featureslib.hold (through cpanel/plesk or ftp,according to what is your hosting provider) and then connect again to your Wordpress admin panel, so that the blank page problem is fixed.